# Shading problems,tris mesh with black marks

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

in Blender I tried to do this low poly beretta that I triangulated and applied normal, roughness albedo and specular maps but in some points I get those black shades.
may it be because of an unclean construction process?
I beveled it and perhaps it was the cause but I really don't know
here the pictures I made

Renders:

[image: render]

[image: render-2]

Topology screenshots:

[image: wireframe]

[image: wireframe (bad)]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Shade Smooth is on. If that is the case, try switching the shading to Flat (Object Mode > Right Click > Shade Flat), or turn Autosmooth on (Object Data Panel > Autosmooth).

Comment: i forgot to say that i'm using edge split... that was the problem, the angle value was too high. you helped me understand though so thanks!